# Aftershot not loading (fully)

Tags: 13.10, software-installation

I installed Aftershot pro (x64) on my Ubuntu 13.10 64bit system but it is not loading (fully). The installation was without any problem. It does load and show me two initial screens.

1st: Choose Folder location for settings & catalog

2nd: Continue Trial version or enter Serial.

Once I click continue, a splash screen appears for split second and then it unloads every time.

NOTE: I do have `ia32-libs` and yes, I downloaded it from official website.

What could be the problem here? Please help me out...

Answer (score 0):

You can mostly get around this using a startup script.  Eg I'm using:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# AfterShot Pro startup script
# make symlinks to this script anywhere in your $PATH
#

FindPath()
{
    if [ "`readlink "$0"`" = "" ]; then
        pushd $(dirname "$0") >/dev/null
        FP="$(pwd)"
        popd >/dev/null
        echo "${FP}" 
    else
        FP=$(readlink "$0"|sed -e "s/ /\\\ /g")
        echo `dirname "${FP}"`
    fi
}


INSTALL_PATH="/opt/AfterShotPro"

LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${INSTALL_PATH}/lib:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}
XLIB_SKIP_ARGB_VISUALS=1
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH
export XLIB_SKIP_ARGB_VISUALS
echo "Install Path:          " ${INSTALL_PATH}
echo "LD_PATH:               " $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
echo "XLIB_SKIP_ARGB_VISUALS:" $XLIB_SKIP_ARGB_VISUALS


if [ -x "${INSTALL_PATH}/bin/AfterShotPro" ]
then
    cd "${INSTALL_PATH}/bin"
    #ldd  "./AfterShotPro" 
    exec "./AfterShotPro"  "$@"
    #echo "all is well in the world"
else
    echo "didn't run it (obviously)"
fi
exit 1
```

**HOWEVER**

I came across your post while looking for an answer to a problem with this approach.  As a side effect it leads the LD_LIBRARY_PATH variable set when running sub-programs, causing them to fail.  I'm sure this is the problem when trying to run something as a post processing option on an export.  I haven't yet verified it, but I suspect it's also why nothing happens when I try to pass an image to an external editor, or view web links (eg help).